# Flutter Web on iOS Safari not showing (rendering??) well

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Hi I made a simple web with Flutter and I made it responsive, so I checked with chrome dev tools if all works properly and it does.

Like this picture, that is from Chrome dev tools

[image]

The thing is that when I deployed with firebase hosting, I tested it on an Iphone 8 plus with safari and the menu is not showing well, and I don't have any idea of why

[image]

As you can see the menu is cutted. Also if you know how to remove the annoying bottom white bar that is created only on mobile web I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If your Flutter app targets the web and uses the CanvasKit renderer, you might have noticed that your app's performance in Safari is way worse than its performance in Chrome. That is because the Safari implementation of WebGL 2.0 is pretty f**ked. Put the following script tag into your index.html and it'll simply disable WebGL 2.0 if the user agent is Safari.

```
<script>
  if (
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") !== -1 &&
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") === -1
  ) {
    var originalGetContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;
    HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function () {
      var contextType = arguments[0];
      if (contextType === "webgl2") {
        return;
      }
      return originalGetContext.apply(
        this,
        [contextType].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)),
      );
    };
  }
</script>
```